# SQLAlchemy `Session.is_modified` returns `True`, even when object columns were not modified

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to detect when an object is modified in [SQLAlchemy's `before_update` mapper event](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_update). From the docs:

> To detect if the column-based attributes on the object have net
>   changes, and will therefore generate an UPDATE statement, use
>   object_session(instance).is_modified(instance,
>   include_collections=False).

However, I'm seeing that `is_modified` is returning `True` even if none of the object's columns have been modified and no `UPDATE` statement is emitted to the database. Below you'll find a working example and the version of SQLAlchemy that I'm using. Any idea on why this is happening? I took a peek at the SQLAlchemy source code for `Session.is_modified`, and it seems to use the `object_state` and the history.

SQLAlchemy version:

```
$ pip freeze | grep SQLAlchemy
SQLAlchemy==1.1.9
```

Source:

```
import logging
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    backref,
    class_mapper,
    relationship,
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker)
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    inspect,
    Column,
    Integer,
    ForeignKey,
    MetaData)


logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parents"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "children"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parents.id"))
    parent = relationship(
        "Parent",
        backref=backref("child", uselist=False),
        single_parent=True,
        cascade="all")


engine = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()
with engine.begin() as connection:
    metadata = Base.metadata
    metadata.create_all(connection)

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@listens_for(Base, "before_update", propagate=True)
def before_update(mapper, connection, target):
    session = Session.object_session(target)

    if session.is_modified(target, include_collections=False):
        logger.info(
            "target of type %s with id %s was modified",
            type(target).__name__,
            getattr(target, "id", None))

        inspr = inspect(target)
        attrs = class_mapper(target.__class__).column_attrs
        for attr in attrs:
            hist = getattr(inspr.attrs, attr.key).history
            logger.info(
                "attribute %s has changes: %s",
                attr.key,
                hist.has_changes())


parent = Parent()
session.add(parent)
session.flush()
child = Child(parent=parent)
session.add(child)
session.flush()
```

Relevant output:

```
2017-11-29 18:07:28,471 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
2017-11-29 18:07:28,476 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2017-11-29 18:07:28,477 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO parents DEFAULT VALUES
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO parents DEFAULT VALUES
2017-11-29 18:07:28,478 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:()
2017-11-29 18:07:28,480 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT children.id AS children_id, children.parent_id AS children_parent_id 
FROM children 
WHERE ? = children.parent_id
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT children.id AS children_id, children.parent_id AS children_parent_id 
FROM children 
WHERE ? = children.parent_id
2017-11-29 18:07:28,480 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:(1,)
INFO:__main__:target of type Parent with id 1 was modified
INFO:__main__:attribute id has changes: False
2017-11-29 18:07:28,483 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO children (parent_id) VALUES (?)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:INSERT INTO children (parent_id) VALUES (?)
2017-11-29 18:07:28,484 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (1,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:(1,)
```

EDIT: Renamed `Child`'s backref to `Parent` from `parent` to `child`.

Comment: `parent`'s *columns* haven't been modified, but its *relationships* have, i.e. `parent.parent` [sic] now contains `child`, when you added `child` to the session.

Comment: I see -- I thought the`include_collections=False` parameter would account for that. With that being said, what's the best way to check if an "UPDATE" will be emitted to the database? Inspect the object and iterate over all of its column attributes?

Comment: `include_collections=False` means it doesn't look at collections, but `parent.child` is not a collection because you've specified `uselist=False`. Your approach of inspecting the history of only column attributes should work -- it's what SQLAlchemy does under the hood anyway.

Comment: @univerio can you please write up as an answer?